# jQuery: Hide element immediately on scroll down

Tags: jquery

I want to hide an element on scroll. However, it doesn't hide until about a quarter/half the window has been scrolled, which is not what I want. It should hide as soon as the scroll begins.

I have an element that keeps fading in and out, until you start scrolling, at which point, it will disappear. Scroll back to the top, it will appear again and start to fade in-fade out.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var $element = $('#scrollDown');
    var $load = true;
    var $pos = ( $(window).scrollTop() );

    (function fadeInOut() {
        setInterval(function () {
            if ($load) {
                $element.fadeIn(750, function () {
                    $element.fadeOut(1000);
                });
            }

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > $pos) {
                    $load = false;
                    $element.fadeOut(1000);
                }
                else {
                    $load = true;
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    }) ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood, you want to disappear the element when you start scrolling and when reteurn to the top, appears again, so I would try to do:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $element.fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        $element.fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

Is that what you need?

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/4uj50cg3/1/

Comment: Cheers! I've forked the JSFiddle and added a CSS bit to make the fade-out animation view-able: http://jsfiddle.net/RuppalSingh/tz7cx865/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change that if statement to something like..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($element.css("opacity") == 1) {
                $load = false;
                $element.fadeOut(1000);
            }
            else {
                $load = true;
            }
        });
```

Now it will trigger as soon as the scroll begins, and only once because of the if statement.